# Which ballast do I use?

Tags: lighting

I have a 7 watt Sylvania CF7DS bulb with a G23 socket, which ballast do I use?

I have tried to contact the fixture manufacturer but the fixture is discontinued.

I have contacted the bulb manufacturer and am still waiting for a reply.

Comment: What is the brand/model of the fixture?

Comment: What does it say on the ballast?

Comment: Open it up far enough to get a photo of the labeling on the ballast.  Post it here or on imgur.  [edit] your question to include it in the question.

Comment: Try these numbers CC579TP, LPL-5-9-TP, FCF-7/9-TP, 4105F2P

Comment: You might be better off replacing the lampe with an LED that fits the G23 socket, such as these: https://www.amazon.co.uk/LED-Bulbs-G23-Light/s?keywords=LED+Bulbs&rh=n:248790031,p_n_feature_three_browse-bin:250335031&c=ts&ts_id=248790031 . Some operate with *no* ballast, and LED's last longer and are a bit more efficient than fluorescents.